# Bash script: argument not found

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script (check_status) by which I am trying to know if a process is running or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
# check argument
if ["$1" == ""];
then
    echo "Invalid argument"
    exit 3
fi

PN=$(ps -ef  | grep $1 | wc -l)

echo "process is $1: executing $PN"

if [ $PN -gt 1 ];
then
    status=OK
    message=UP
    exit=0
else
    status=CRITICAL
    message=DOWN
    exit=2
fi

echo "$status - $1 is $message"

exit $exit
```

However, when I run this from shell `sh checkstatus xyz` I get this:

```
check_status: 3: check_status: [xyz: not found
process is xyz: executing 3
OK - xyz is UP
```

Now, my first problem is the `check_status: 3: check_status: [xyz: not found` error. I dont know why its showing up.

Next,there is no process xyz running in my server. So, as per my understanding I am running `ps -ef | grep xyz | wc -l` in the shell which should echo `1` if no process is running. But, I am getting 3.

How do I fix this?

**Update**

I changed `if ["$1" == ""];` to `if [ "$1" = "" ]` Now I am not getting the error. But still my `PN=$(ps -ef  | grep $1 | wc -l)` is returning 3.

I then updated `PN=$(ps -ef  | grep $1 | wc -l)` to `PN=$(ps -ef  | grep $1 )` which gave me the following response:

```
admin    14674  4570  0 12:03 pts/2    00:00:00 sh check_status xyz
admin    14675 14674  0 12:03 pts/2    00:00:00 sh check_status xyz
admin    14677 14675  0 12:03 pts/2    00:00:00 grep xyz
```

One `sh check_status xyz` and one `grep xyz` makes seance to me. But, any idea why I see two of them ?

Comment: Spaces around `[` and `]` are important. `[` is a command not a syntax feature. Also look into `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`.

Comment: I'm about to write a manifesto entitled `[ considered harmful`. Nobody ever needs to ask why `test"$1" = ""` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Please check my update

Comment: It would help to see the output of `ps -ef | grep "$1"` (quote the `$1`, by they way).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please check my update again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) As mentioned elsewhere, you'll need spaces around "[" and "]".

(2) If your `ps` supports the -c option, you should consider using it.  Otherwise, if you use `ps`, you will need to parse the output in some way.  (You might want to insert "| tee /dev/tty" to see what your ps command is producing.) But is grep (or pgrep) really what you want here?  The messages your script is producing suggest otherwise.

(3) If, for example, you want an exact match of the basename, consider the following (which is broken down into separate steps so you can more easily adapt it to your purpose):

```
ps -c | awk '{print $4}' | grep "^$x\$"
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. I want to know if my Perl scripts are running or not. I just checked `ps -c`  it seems using this I can see how many perl script I am running. But for my case I want to check for specific scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the spaces around `[` that others have mentioned, you should change this:

```
PN=$(ps -ef  | grep $1 | wc -l)
```

to this:

```
PN=$(pidof $1 | wc -w)
```

That will get you a count of running processes that match the name you specified.

The reason you're getting a greater count than expected from your original code is because the grep command also adds one to the count, and it will also produce a hit on any other process that might happen to contain the same characters in its name as the process being targeted. Using `pidof` eliminates both of these factors.